# Issue with react-native-gesture-handler

Tags: react-native, react-native-gesture-handler

i'm having a issue and i've been looking to solve it in days, i've implemented this for using zoom+scroll.

```
import React, { useRef, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { View, Image, StyleSheet, PanResponder, Animated } from 'react-native';
import { PinchGestureHandler, State, PanGestureHandler, TapGestureHandler } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';

const ZoomableScrollView = ({ children }) => {
  const [scale, setScale] = useState(1);
  const baseScale = useRef(new Animated.Value(1)).current;
  const pinchScale = useRef(new Animated.Value(1)).current;
  const scaleValue = useRef(1);
  const pan = useRef(new Animated.ValueXY()).current;
  const [doubleTapDetected, setDoubleTapDetected] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    let timer;
    if (doubleTapDetected) {
      timer = setTimeout(() => {
        setDoubleTapDetected(false);
      }, 100); // Restablecer el estado después de 500 ms (ajusta el tiempo según tus necesidades)
    }
    return () => clearTimeout(timer);
  }, [doubleTapDetected]);

  const onPinchGestureEvent = Animated.event(
    [
      {
        nativeEvent: { scale: pinchScale },
      },
    ],
    { useNativeDriver: true }
  );

  const onPinchHandlerStateChange = (event) => {
    if (event.nativeEvent.oldState === State.ACTIVE) {
      scaleValue.current *= event.nativeEvent.scale;
      baseScale.setValue(scaleValue.current);
      pinchScale.setValue(1);
    }
  };

  const panResponder = PanResponder.create({
    onMoveShouldSetPanResponder: () => true,
    onPanResponderMove: (event, gestureState) => {
      const { dx, dy } = gestureState;
      // Check if the movement is large enough to be considered a valid pan gesture
      if (Math.abs(dx) > 2 || Math.abs(dy) > 2) {
        // Update a temporary variable
        const newPan = { x: pan.x._value + dx, y: pan.y._value + dy };
        // Apply the changes to the pan value
        pan.setValue(newPan);
      }
    },
    onPanResponderRelease: () => {
      Animated.spring(pan, { toValue: { x: 0, y: 0 }, useNativeDriver: false }).start();
    },
  });
  

  const scrollRef = useRef(null);

  return (
    <PinchGestureHandler
      onGestureEvent={onPinchGestureEvent}
      onHandlerStateChange={onPinchHandlerStateChange}
      scale={scale}
      simultaneousHandlers={panResponder}
    >
      <Animated.View style={styles.container}>
        <PanGestureHandler
          onGestureEvent={Animated.event([{ nativeEvent: { translationX: pan.x, translationY: pan.y } }], { useNativeDriver: false })}
        >
          <Animated.View style={styles.container}>
            <TapGestureHandler
              onHandlerStateChange={({ nativeEvent }) => {
                if (nativeEvent.state === State.ACTIVE) {
                  setDoubleTapDetected(true);
                }
              }}
              numberOfTaps={2}
            >
              <Animated.View style={styles.container}>
                <Animated.ScrollView
                  ref={scrollRef}
                  contentContainerStyle={styles.contentContainer}
                  maximumZoomScale={5}
                  minimumZoomScale={1}
                  showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
                  showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
                  bouncesZoom={true}
                  pinchGestureEnabled={true}
                  scrollEnabled={true}
                  style={{ width: '100%', height: '100%' }}
                >
                  <Animated.View
                    style={[
                      styles.imageContainer,
                      {
                        transform: [
                          { scale: baseScale },
                          { translateX: pan.x },
                          { translateY: pan.y },
                        ],
                      },
                    ]}
                  >
                    {children}
                  </Animated.View>
                </Animated.ScrollView>
              </Animated.View>
            </TapGestureHandler>
          </Animated.View>
        </PanGestureHandler>
      </Animated.View>
    </PinchGestureHandler>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    flexGrow: 1
  },
  contentContainer: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  imageContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});

export default ZoomableScrollView;
```

The code is having the following behaviour:

1. When you tap+swipe to any of the sides (up, down, left, right) the screen goes to the top by itself
2. After this tap, if you don't release your finger from the screen, scrolling and zooming are working perfectly
3. If you release your finger from the screen and then tap the screen again, the behavior of 1 is repeated.

I want to be able to tap the screen anytime without getting that automatically scroll to top. Can someone give me a hand?